# Is Torchlight a Multiplayer game?

Tags: torchlight

I loved Diablo II when I was younger, and now I (just) noticed [Torchlight](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchlight).

Is Torchlight a multiplayer game? Does it support co-operative mode?

Comment: Really? You came here to ask a question that was so easily answered by a google search? Not even that, one look at the steam page tells you it's single player only... Am I just getting too overly bugged by this? If I am, my apologies, but... seriously?

Comment: @Aeo Two things: 1) Just with Stack Overflow, et. al., this site is meant to be the place people get their answers. That really means that no answer or question is too trivial.  2) I *didn't* know the answer. I searched and saw that there was an MMO coming out, but that didn't answer whether or not Torchlight had a co-operative mode.

Comment: @Aeo - agreed with George. The great thing with these sites is that you can get great answers, directly to your question, without cruising forums and other articles from a google search. Also, he got his answer in less than 5 minutes, for a beginning site, I think it's not too bad. Also, if you run a google search for this particular question title, you will find random forum posts on other sites, or pages containing multiplayer and torchlight in the same page. Ultimately, they give you the answer, but not directly.

Comment: @gnoupi that's the problem I ran into.  I had a friend suggest that we try it out together, so I searched to see if it had a co-op mode. The fact that it doesn't have an MMO (yet) doesn't necessarily mean it doesn't have a co-operative experience (How many negatives can you put in a sentence and still have it make sense?).

Comment: and just like Stack Overflow the really simple questions get a lot of votes...

Answer (score 22, accepted):

It's not a multiplayer game. They focused only on a single player for now.

They are currently working on a MMO which will be based on the same engine.

More details on the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Torchlight#Relationship_to_upcoming_MMO):

> Max Schaefer, Runic Games CEO and
>   former Mythos executive producer,
>   explained the reasoning behind
>   releasing both a single player game
>   and an MMO. The single player game is
>   intended to introduce the Torchlight
>   game world to the public ahead of the
>   MMO. Further, it would allow the team
>   to get a released game under their
>   belts sooner than if they had
>   immediately started on the MMO.
>   Also, while the Torchlight MMO will be
>   a separate game, it will share the
>   same action RPG gameplay and some of
>   the art assets developed for the
>   single player game.
>
> The MMO will feature some different
>   game mechanics and a wider variety of
>   environments, including a shared
>   "over-world." Runic has
>   entered into a partnership with
>   Chinese online game developer and
>   operator Perfect World Co., Ltd. to
>   publish the MMO worldwide.
>
> Because the MMO is planned to be
>   free-to-play, it can be seen as a
>   "free MMO upgrade" to the
>   single-player Torchlight game.

*For the persons interested, even more details in an [interview given to Gamasutra](http://www.gamasutra.com/php-bin/news_index.php?story=23442).*

Answer (score 16):

Torchlight is not a multiplayer game, however Torchlight 2 will feature multiplayer and will be released Spring 2011. It will also feature full mod support in multiplayer as well.

---

From [Torchlight 2 Website](http://www.torchlight2game.com/)

> CO-OP ACTION The most exciting new
> feature of Torchlight II is the
> multiplayer element. Play with your
> friends, and use the free peer-to-peer
> matchmaking service to meet new
> players of a similar level and
> interest. Together players will
> discover expansive randomized outdoor
> areas and deep ominous caverns; random
> instanced and persistent dungeons, a
> huge variety of all new monsters and
> villains, endless variations of loot
> to find, and quests to complete.
> Players journey through the perilous
> Overworld, enjoying all new weather
> features, time of day events, and a
> rich and cunning story to drive
> gameplay.
>
> Multi-player – Play with your friends
> over a local area network, or over the
> Internet. A free matchmaking
> peer-to-peer service lets you make new
> friends for exciting co-op play.

From [PC Gamer Torchlight 2 Interview](http://www.pcgamer.com/2010/08/04/torchlight-2-interview-with-runic-games/) with Runic Game founders:

> Max Schaefer: It’s peer-to-peer co-op play with just your friends. It’s a halfway step to the MMO.
>
> Travis Baldree: It’ll be free online play. It’s not a multiplayer extension for Torchlight, it’s a full sequel, with lots of new stuff that wasn’t in the original game, but it’ll have full multiplayer support. You can play through the singleplayer story in multiplayer co-op. We’re playing multiplayer in the office right now. We’re trying to basically look at all the things people wanted out of Torchlight, that we didn’t ship in the initial game, and we’re trying to incorporate as many of those as possible.

**UPDATE**
[Torchlight 2 will offer free mod tools, full mod support in multiplayer](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/09/08/torchlight-2-will-offer-free-mod-tools-full-mod-support-in-mult/)

> But because of the addition of multiplayer, I was concerned about how mods will be shared now. The rep confirmed to me that players will be able to use the new multiplayer framework to find games incorporating mods but, better yet, all XP earned in these games will stay with your character. I was promised persistence across all games, be they mods or standard games.
> As stated in the quotes, multiplayer will be free and will resemble Diablo 2 more than Hellgate: London.

Runic Games CEO, Max Schaefer, believes that [Torchlight 3 will be released before Diablo 3](http://www.joystiq.com/2010/08/24/torchlight-3-out-before-diablo-3-runic-ceo-hypothesizes/)

> Runic Games CEO Max Schaefer respectfully believes that a third Torchlight game could be out before Blizzard's Diablo 3 -- a joke we'd made when the second Torchlight was recently announced. The executive tells us that the efficient size of the Runic team, which has a corporate goal to never grow above 40, would have the ability to get out another significantly upgraded sequel before Blizzard's behemoth arrived. Torchlight and its sequel have both had brisk development cycles lasting less than a year.

I would assume that Torchlight 3 will also be a multiplayer game.

Answer (score 1):

Torchlight is not a multiplayer game, they claim the next one will be.

However, there's some interaction between your characters, if you play more of them. There's a common stash in the town, which allows you to pass items between them. This is really cool if you play with a certain char and find a good item for another char.

Answer (score 0):

Though Torchlight is not multiplayer there is a downloadable mod that can make it multiplayer.  Also, Torchlight 2 will be multiplayer, currently estimated to release in late summer, 2012.  Runic plans on developing a MMO based on Torchlight in the future.

Comment: Welcome to Arqade. Unless you can provide a link to this mod, this answer does not bring anything that wasn't said previously, and we wants to avoid duplicate content.

Comment: [Torchlight Multiplayer Mod](http://code.google.com/p/tlmp/) I haven't used it in a long time, it was very buggy and incomplete once upon a time.