# Is Torchlight 2 cross-platform coop possible ? (Switch + PC)

Tags: torchlight-2

I would like to know if a coop PC + switch is possible for Torchlight 2.

I read [this post](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/3543/is-torchlight-a-multiplayer-game), but it did not help. This other [reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/cedqy3/will_torchlight_2_for_consoles_be_cross_platform/) does not really have the answer either.

Can I consider that if there is no answer, the answer is no ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe the answer is no.

(I also played TL 1&2. 1 was clearly single, 2 had LAN/IP possibility for PC, but cross-platform is a huge endeavour to take. If there would be a chance, that could be visible on hosting a game, showing up several different console network integration, and game discovery - and I don't see such in there. Modding is still a possibility, but I think vanilla game is clearly out of this.)

Forgive me to link another Reddit, it is 4 days old by today:
https://www.reddit.com/r/Torchlight/comments/iv5mds/torchlight_2_pc_and_switch/